# Difficulty of Meiji literature

Tags: readings

I'm currently self-teaching myself Japanese with the aim of becoming a proficient reader so I can read Japanese liteature without the aid of a translation.
I've heard mention a few times of the language reforms that took place in 1946; some of the authors I'm interested in reading (Ichiyo and Soseki) are from about 50 years before this. 
Am I going to encounter serious problems when trying to read their work once I become proficient reading post-reform literature?
Any pointers anyone can provide would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I think this question would be a much better fit for the site if you reformulated it asking about the major differences between pre- and post-reform literature (and then you can decide individually if you might encounter serious problems due to them). Of course leaving the motivation for the question in would be fine, I think.

Comment: I voted to close, but I think the question turns out to be irrelevant due to a root problem: as far as I know, there's no direct route for foreigners to learn pre-war Japanese so whatever "serious problems" you might encounter by learning contemporary Japanese first will have to be faced regardless of whether learning contemporary Japanese produces said problems. Thus, it seems like it would be much better to ask about the differences as Darius suggests.  (My wife reads 明治日本語 for her program; as a Japanese learner I don't find it that hard to read: more kanji, some minor grammar changes)

Comment: But let's be clear: there is a significant difference between classical Japanese and modern Japanese, and one finds [both in Meiji literature](http://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E8%A8%80%E6%96%87%E4%B8%80%E8%87%B4).